# How to find all nodes between two nodes in graph database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb, opencypher

I`m using Cypher query language and I need to find nodes between node A and E. (A->B->C->D->E)

Next query returns all nodes including A and E, but i need to exclude them, to have B, C, D nodes. How can I filter my query result?

```
MATCH p= (A:City{name: 'City1'})-[:LINKED*]->(E:City{name: "City5"}) return nodes(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you might do this, but a simple option is to just index into the node list using:

```
return nodes(p)[1..-1]
```